# Logstash running at 100% with no apparent reason

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, logstash, elastic-stack

I have a `Logstash` install on AWS with Amazon ECS optimised linux AMI (Debian Stretch) and it has a simple `Logstash` setup:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/home/ec2-user/**/*.*"
    }
    file {
        path => "/var/log/ecs/*.*"
    }
}
filter {
  mutate {
    add_field => {
      "Cluster" => "${CLUSTER}"
      "InstanceID" => "${INSTANCEID}"
    }
  }
}
output{
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["https://search-b12es-*************************"]
    }
}
```

The problem is that my cpu is running 100% for no reason and its Logstash's fault:
[top output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwQSC.png)
I followed some threads in SO and other forums and they suggested to execute `sudo stop logstash-web` to disable `logstash-web` but i also found that it is already fixed. My setup is quite simple and i don't really believe that the problem is logic. If anyone knows a solution please advice.
I used `/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/logstash.conf --path.settings /etc/logstash/ &` in `user data` to start `Logstash`

Comment: Why are you monitoring every file under `/home/ec2-user`?

Comment: Also, how much data is flowing into your ElasticSearch cluster? Is this a situation where Logstash is doing a lot of processing but not generating a lot of output, or where it's actually doing a lot of work?

Comment: home/ec2-user is empty and logging is not much (100req per day). Load is 100% even on machine startup with no logging at all. I am monitoring the home folder cause there the apps are creating subfolders with individual logs, but as i said they are below 100 for a day per app (7 apps in total)

Comment: Given the information that you've provided, there's not much specific help that anyone can give you. There's _something_ in your environment that's causing the problem, because thousands of people use Logstash in production without a problem. My best advice is to enable [internal logging](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/logging.html) to see why your environment causes this CPU consumption.